# SLAProcess in Test

Tags: apex, entitlements

I'm working on a trigger that will add an entitlement to an account after the account is inserted. In addition, the entitlement that is created will also have an SLA process ID associated with it. While writing some tests, I noticed that I was able to retrieve the SLAProcess without using the (seeAllData =true) annotation.

Here's a snippet of the apex class:

```
        sla = [SELECT Id, NAME FROM Slaprocess WHERE IsActive = true LIMIT 1];

        for(Account a : accounts){
            Entitlement e = new Entitlement();
            e.SlaProcessId  = sla.id;
            e.AccountId     = a.id;
            e.Name          = ENTITLEMENT_NAME;
            entitlements.add(e);
        }

        insert entitlements;
```

Since we cant insert SLA processes through Apex, I'm curious as to how that query brought back all SLA process ID's in my org.

Any thoughts on why this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design. Salesforce doesn't allow us to create Entitlement Process (SLAProcess) from test class.

So, as a pre-caution during deployment, you need to create entitlement process in new org or production and then you will run the test classes, otherwise it will fail.

Update:

> DML operation INSERT not allowed on SlaProcess.

Refer this my answer here [How to set Entitlement Process Name in a Test?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/173793/how-to-set-entitlement-process-name-in-a-test/173805)

Comment: If I run "_SELECT Id FROM SlaProcess_" in my Dev org I get ->`sObject type 'SlaProcess' is not supported.` (tooling API is unchecked). Do you know why is that?

Comment: did you activate Entitlement Settings?

Comment: Nope. It works now :)

Comment: Hey @SantanuBoral,
So just to be clear, being able to query SLA process without seeAllData is working as designed? Have you come across any documentation from SFDC that states that? Seems odd that this object is accessible in test

Comment: refer my updated answer